# Remove special elements from multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

My array looks like this:

```
var my_array=[
  [[1,0], [2,2], [4,1]],
  [[4,9], [3,1], [4,2]],
  [[5,6], [1,5], [9,0]]
]
```

I'd like to filter the `my_array` above and remove all arrays (e.g. `[[4,9], [3,1], [4,2]]`) from the array above IF all `child arrays` of the array have no specific value (e.g. `0`) at the 1. position (`child array[1]`)

So my result should look like this:

```
var result_array=[
  [[1,0], [2,0], [4,1]],
  [[5,6], [1,5], [9,0]]
]
```

> See above: Remove second array from `my_array` because the second child arrays do not include a `0`-column at the first index.

My idea was to use something like this code, but I can not really get it working:

```js
var my_array=[
    [[1,0], [2,2], [4,1]],
    [[4,9], [3,1], [4,2]],
    [[5,6], [1,5], [9,0]]
]
  
 result_array = my_array.filter(function(item){ return item[1] != 0 })
console.log(JSON.stringify(result_array))
```

Comment: What do you call child arrays?

Comment: e.g `[4,9]` this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way would be to use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in the `filter` on the outer array to find any array in it matching our criterion, and to use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (or `Array#indexOf` on older browsers, comparing with -1 for not found) in the `find` callback to see if the child array contains `0`.

In ES2015+

```js
var my_array=[
  [[1,0], [2,2], [4,1]],
  [[4,9], [3,1], [4,2]],
  [[5,6], [1,5], [9,0]]
];
var filtered = my_array.filter(middle => middle.some(inner => inner.includes(0)));
console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or in ES5:

```js
var my_array=[
  [[1,0], [2,2], [4,1]],
  [[4,9], [3,1], [4,2]],
  [[5,6], [1,5], [9,0]]
];
var filtered = my_array.filter(function(middle) {
  return middle.some(function(inner) {
    return inner.indexOf(0) != -1;
  });
});
console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Ooops, if you see `Array#find` above, hit refresh. Should be `#some`.

Comment: Think OP wants  position specific test in middle arrays

Comment: @charlietfl: Thanks, but apparently not, as OP has accepted an answer using exactly my code, posted well after my answer.